# Angularjs ngclass based on $index

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to style my div based on the index of the ng-repeat, where i am applying two different styles. The row with even index would have the all classes specified for the odd one in addition to other classes.

**Controller:**

```
 var odd= { 'class1' : true, 'class2': true ,'class3': false,'class4': false} ;
 var even = { 'class1' : true, 'class2': true ,'class3': true,'class4': true} ;

 $scope.applyColumnClasses = function(index)
  {

     if ( index % 2 == 0) 
          return even;
     else 
         return odd;
  }
```

**View:**

```
<div  ng-repeat="a in articles"  ng-class="applyColumnClasses($index)" >
```

I have more than five classes that should be added to the even row. Is there more elegant way to do this?

Like setting a string variable as "class1, class2" for odd, then in case it was even I just append the other classes and return it.

I am trying to write cleaner code. May be declare one object rather two as I already did.

Any thoughts...

Comment: Simplest way is using `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways :

```
class="commonClass" ng-class="{'evenClass':$even,'oddClass':$odd}"
```

or

```
class="commonClass"  ng-class-even="'evenClass'" ng-class-odd="'oddClass'"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can apply common classes directly without binding and leave the rest as it is:

```
<div  ng-repeat="a in articles" class="class1 class2" ng-class="applyColumnClasses($index)" >
```